# No override found for vtkRenderer/ vtkRenderWindow

Tags: cmake, vtk

I'm new to vtk and when I was running a small example, it generates two errors,

> No override found for vtkRenderer
>
> No override found for vtkRenderWindow

I googled this problem and couldn't find a proper solution.

Comment: Please add the example you tried to your question.

Comment: Does this really have something to do with _CMake_? Looks more like a compiler error, not CMake error.

Comment: @YakovL Do you want me to add the source code?

Comment: "I was running a small example" - if it is small, yes show the source code here. How you would expect us to help you with an error without seeing what is causing it? (of'course, sometimes one may propose a proper "educated guess", but as a general rule, you should provide the relevant pieces of code, the expected behaviour and the actual behaviour (with error text if there's any))

Answer (score 12):

I had such a problem when I was trying to make a VTK project without CMake, the solution was to use those two lines:

```
#include <vtkAutoInit.h> 
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingOpenGL2)
```

So if you are using CMake, then you probably have skipped some step while building your VTK environment.

Comment: Did you add this "VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingOpenGL2)" line before the main?